# Rails - Sorting a model using order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Question model, which I am getting a selection of items from (@rejected). I then want to calculate an :approval_rating attribute for each item and sort the collection by that attribute. I'm trying to do so with the following:

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true) 
    if @rejected   
      @rejected = @rejected.map do |q|
        upvotes = q.get_upvotes.size
        downvotes = q.get_downvotes.size
        total_votes = Float(upvotes + downvotes)
        q.approval_rating = (upvotes/total_votes*100).round(2)
        q.save
      end
      @rejected = @rejected.order('approval_rating DESC')
    end
  end
```

This is giving me the error when attempting to sort: *undefined method `order' for [true, true, true]:Array*

I also tried this with

```
@rejected = @rejected.sort_by(&:approval_ratings)
```

and got the error: *undefined method `approval_rating' for true:TrueClass*

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates an `Array` of the value `true` (see below)

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true) 
  if @rejected   
    @rejected = @rejected.map do |q|
      upvotes = q.get_upvotes.size
      downvotes = q.get_downvotes.size
      total_votes = Float(upvotes + downvotes)
      q.approval_rating = (upvotes/total_votes*100).round(2)
      q.save # <= this is what gets added to the array from map, which is 'true'
    end
    @rejected = @rejected.order('approval_rating DESC')
  end
end
```

And `true:TrueClass` doesn't respond to `approval_rating`.

There are some other problems with your code. This:

```
@questions.where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true)
```

will always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so this:

```
if @rejected
```

will always return true.

You probably want to consider using `each` instead of `map`. But, that will still return an `Array`, I believe. So you still won't be able to do `@rejected.order('approval_rating DESC')`

I *think* you should be able to do:

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.
                where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true).
                each do |q|
                  upvotes     = q.get_upvotes.size
                  downvotes   = q.get_downvotes.size
                  total_votes = Float(upvotes + downvotes)
                  q.approval_rating.update(
                    approval_rating: (upvotes/total_votes*100).round(2)
                  )
                end.
                sort_by(&:approval_rating)
end
```

I'm not 100% sure your sort order will be in the right direction, so you may need to check that.

Personally, it seems to me that you would be better off to put the `approval_rating` logic in the `Question` model. Perhaps something like:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

  def update_approval_rating
    upvotes     = get_upvotes.size
    downvotes   = get_downvote.size
    total_votes = Float(upvotes+downvotes)
    update(
      approval_rating: (upvotes/total_votes*100).round(2)
    )
  end

end
```

In which case you could do

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.
                where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true).
                each{|q| q.update_approval_rating}.
                sort_by(&:approval_rating)
end
```

It seems to me like you might consider setting `approval_rating` every time a `Question` gets a vote (in your `QuestionsController` presumably). Then you don't have to deal with setting `approval_rating` in the `index` action. Besides, `index` should be idempotent, so modifying records there seems smelly (IMO).

Then, you could end up with something more like:

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.
                where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true).
                order(approval_rating: :desc)
end
```

Ah... So much better.

You could even add some class methods on to your `Question` model, something like:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  class << self 

    def for_question_number(ques_num)
      where(ques_num: ques_num)
    end 

    def rejected
      where(rejected: true)
    end

    def best_first
      order(approval_rating: :desc)
    end

  end
end
```

In which case you could do:

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.
                for_question_number(params[:ques_num]).
                rejected.
                best_first
end
```

If the future you decides to determine what is "best" some other way at some point, then you can make the changes to the `best_first` method in your `Question` model and your `index` action is non-the-wiser.

And now it's starting to feel like rainbows and lollipops in here.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `map` which returns an array. If you want to apply AR query methods such `order`, you need to supply `ActiveRecord::Relation` class.  The simplest solution here - perform another query to sort the relation based on the modified field or sort `@rejected` with ruby using `sort_by`.

```
def index
  ...
  @rejected = @questions.where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true) 
  if @rejected.present?   
     @rejected.each do |q|
        upvotes = q.get_upvotes.size
        downvotes = q.get_downvotes.size
        total_votes = Float(upvotes + downvotes)
        q.approval_rating = (upvotes/total_votes*100).round(2)
        q.save
      end
      @rejected = @questions.where("ques_num=? AND rejected=?", params[:ques_num], true).order('approval_rating DESC')
    end
  end
end
```

Note: Your `@rejected` always == true (Empty relation [] treats as true). Use `@rejected.present?`

Perhaps it would be better to write the code from iterator to the SQL/AR statement

Comment: What is the class of the object returned by `@rejected.each do |q| ... end`?

Comment: You're right, it's Array. OP must perform another query with same params after editing each question.

Comment: Or sort the `Array`, as below.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the value of `if @rejected.present?`?

Comment: `true` if something *present* in the relation (if `@rejected` not empty)

Comment: Yes, but why is that valuable? If `@rejected` is not `.present?`, then `.each` won't do anything. And then you reset `@rejected`, which doesn't really benefit from the `.present?` test. So, if you removed the `.present?` test, would this approach behave any differently?

Comment: I don't know why OP inserted this condition :) Maybe he has another code which he didn't post as unimportant